# Android - How to access a getter method in parent Activity from Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a FragmentActivity that has the values I needed to be used in a Fragment.

This is the way I do it, but I have no idea on how to access the getter in the FragmentActivity.

ItemDetailActivity

```
public class ItemDetailActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    public String getItem_id() {
        return item_id;
    }

    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }
    ...
}
```

ItemPhotosFragment

```
public class ItemPhotosFragment extends Fragment {
    public ItemPhotosFragment() {
        user_id = getActivity().getUser_id();
    }
}
```

As you can see in the FragmentActivity, I'm implementing TabListener. So I'm want to pass the values to all tabs (fragments).

How do I do this? Is accessing from getActivity a best practice because I saw some of the solutions here suggesting it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

type cast into parent activity:

write this code in `onActivityCreated` inside your fragment not in constructor:

```
user_id =((ItemDetailActivity )getActivity()).getUser_id();
```

It's about fragment's [life-cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding). `onActivityCreated` is called when fragment becomes part of the activity and this is the first callback from where getActivity() doesn't return null

Comment: `getActivity()` will return null if fragment is not attached

Comment: @AimanB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android. this could help

Comment: you can write this code in any of the fragment functions but do ensure that those methods come after onAttach() in fragment life cycle.

Comment: Raghu, that solution only works with specific fragments, am I right? Because I'm using tabs (multiple fragments) here. So I would want to access it all from one place.

Comment: Do I need to put the methods in onAttach() method @SohailAziz? I did what Vipul said, and it also worked. What's the difference? Thanks anyway.

Comment: it's about fragments life cycle. first onCreateView is called and onActivityCreated is called when becomes part of the activity and this is first callback from where getActivity() doesn't return null

Comment: onAttach() is Called when the fragment has been associated with the activity (the Activity is passed in here). look at fragment [life cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. While initializing the fragment in activity, you can do `myFragment.setArguments(Bundle bundle)` and you can put your params in this bundle.
2. The other way is mentioned in above example.

Comment: In first approach, you can get the same bundle inside your fragment by  this.getArguments();

Answer (score 1):

Above solution provided are good. i think the same can be done in a much cleaner way using delegation pattern.
Here is the link for this.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface